# How to insert html (data) attribute to Wordpress Divi theme module?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, animate.css, wow.js

I am developing a website using Wordpress **Divi Theme.** I am using **Animate.css** and **Wow.js** for triggering custom animations when user scrolls the web page. In the module, **Divi Advanced CSS** section, there is a place which can enter custom classes. So, I can enter Animation type and also initialize wow.js. But I cannot find a place to enter **data-wow-duration, data-wow-delay, data-wow-offset etc...** Therefor, I am looking for a way to insert these attributes to the Divi theme module. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Why don't you flag the accepted answer as such?

Answer (score 1):

In the Advanced CSS tab,  you can only add ID / Class and CSS to the different parts( sections / rows / modules )

Therefore, you can add your attributes via a JQuery file, in your theme folder, selecting the class put in the Advanced CSS tab earlier

Here's the link to add attributes via JQuery : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Cheers,

Comment: Pretty terrible solution tbh - Divi needs somewhere that we can pack in extra attributes on the generated elements to make these external library additions (and custom code) easier